# mongodb - How to update a value inside an array?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update the following row:

```
{
    "_id": "80a7",
    "title": "Is React better than Angular?",
    "options": [{
        "option": "Yes",
        "vote": 0
    }, {
        "option": "No",
        "vote": 0
    }],
```

Assuming in `api/vote`, the value passed is "Yes", How can I update the vote for Yes by `$inc` by 1 ?

```
  const {id, option} = req.body;

  const db = await getMongoDb();

  await db.collection('polls').updateOne(
    {
    _id: id,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        options: ???,
      },
    },
  );
```

What should be ??? replaced with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with `arrayFilters`.

```
await db.collection('polls').updateOne({
  _id: id
},
{
  $inc: {
    "options.$[opt].vote": 1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "opt.option": "Yes"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fPM-N6Q8rSQ)

Comment: What about `$inc` to increment the vote each time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what's your meaning.

Comment: So after 12 votes, it should be `"option": "Yes",
        "vote": 12`

Comment: The `$inc` will increment the current value by provided input, so let's say your vote for `"option": "Yes"` is 12, after the update, it will become 13.